# Would it be okay to put onSnapshot() inside an onAuthStateChanged()?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have one collection of users with some data in firestore (with their uid as the key). After login, first thing I want to do is show the user data and the user being able to modify it, but if onSnapshot execute outside  onAuthStateChanged before I retrieve the user uid to get the doc ref, it will fail the first time which causes my code to stop executing. For some reason that error is not caught, so is it good practice to put it in onAuthStateChanged to make sure that I get the user uid before the first time onSnapshot is executed?

Comment: Welcome to SO! The question is a little vague. @frankvanpuffelen answer is correct but if the goal is to read Firebase data - *"After login, first thing I want to do"* the `userCredential` object returned from `signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)` contains their account info (uid) and you can use that immediately. See [login](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#sign_in_a_user_with_an_email_address_and_password) with `const user = userCredential.user;` *After that* use onAuthStateChanged to monitor their online presence. That may be a simpler approach.

Answer (score 2):

If your `onSnapshot` listener depends on the current user, then it's idiomatic to attach that listener on an `onAuthStateChanged` handler when the `user` becomes not null, and subsequently detach it there when the `user` becomes null again.